# Python automation using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I want link automation using Python so when I click on webpage with links on it. It automatically calls a number on Skype. The number is like `hyperlinked{callto:+181082871772}`. I want to automate this process so theirs a button on which when I click start It automatically read first link and click on it so it goes to skype caller. Here is the code I am using but its not working:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import webbrowser
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

def get_links_from_html_file(file_path):
    with open(file_path, "r") as file:
        html_content = file.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "html.parser")
    links = [a.get("href") for a in soup.find_all("a")]
    return links

def make_call():
    global current_link_index
    
    if current_link_index < len(links):
        webbrowser.open(links[current_link_index])
        current_link_index += 1
    else:
        messagebox.showinfo("Info", "All links have been clicked.")

def hang_up():
    # Implement any hang-up action you need here
    pass

def main():
    global links, current_link_index
    
    html_file_path = "D:\student\sheet.htm"
    links = get_links_from_html_file(html_file_path)
    current_link_index = 0

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Webpage Link Clicker")

    make_call_button = tk.Button(root, text="Make Call", command=make_call)
    make_call_button.pack(pady=10)

    hang_up_button = tk.Button(root, text="Hang Up", command=hang_up)
    hang_up_button.pack()

    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I tried adding the code but the script is not working properly.